# Сгруппировать картинки по тегу

Tags: javascript

Мне приходит массив объектов, к примеру:

```
0: {type: "gif", id: "BZ9K1QrgcJr20", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/dog-puppy-BZ9K1QrgcJr20", imageTag: "dog", …}
1: {type: "gif", id: "E5EUmJssOooGk", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-E5EUmJssOooGk", imageTag:"cat" …}
```

С помощью groupBy из lodash я их сгруппировал по imageTag, чтобы можно было выводить картинки по введённому тэгу:

```
{dog: Array(1), cat: Array(1)}
```

Суть в том, что мне нужно выводить картинки группами, то есть, если тег = "dog", то все картинки с таким тегом выводятся вместе, затем группа картинок с другим тегом и тд.
Мне непонятно, как именно реализовать вывод по группам.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую воспользоваться [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let array = [
  {type: "gif", id: "BZ9K1QrgcJr20", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/dog-puppy-BZ9K1QrgcJr20", imageTag: "dog"},
  {type: "gif", id: "E5EUmJssOooGk", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-E5EUmJssOooGk", imageTag:"cat"},
  {type: "gif", id: "BZ9K1QrgcJr201", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/dog-puppy-BZ9K1QrgcJr201", imageTag: "dog"},
  {type: "gif", id: "E5EUmJssOooGk1", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-E5EUmJssOooGk1", imageTag:"cat"}
];

let result = array.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if(acc[item.imageTag]) {
    acc[item.imageTag].push(item);
  } else {    
    acc[item.imageTag] = [item];
  }  
 return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: У меня аналогичный результат при использовании lodash.groupBy, меня интересует, как при постоянно дополняющихся тегах реализовать перебор этих объектов и уже поместить всё в один массив с тегом и прочей информацией

Comment: Формируете array из [...document.getElementsBy...].map(item => {type: get typefrom item, id: ..., url: ...})

Answer (score 1):

Вытащить все теги массива уникально, используйте `Set()`:

```js
let data = [{type: "gif", id: "BZ9K1QrgcJr20", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/dog-puppy-BZ9K1QrgcJr20", imageTag: "dog",},
{type: "gif", id: "E5EUmJssOooGk", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-E5EUmJssOooGk", imageTag:"cat"},
{type: "gif", id: "BZ9K1QrgcJr20", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/dog-puppy-BZ9K1QrgcJr20", imageTag: "dog"},
{type: "gif", id: "E5EUmJssOooGk", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-E5EUmJssOooGk", imageTag:"cat"}
];

console.log([... new Set(data.map(a=>a.imageTag))]);
```

Если вам надо сгруппировать объекты массива по тегу, используйте `.sort()`:

```js
let data = [{type: "gif", id: "BZ9K1QrgcJr20", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/dog-puppy-BZ9K1QrgcJr20", imageTag: "dog",},
{type: "gif", id: "E5EUmJssOooGk", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-E5EUmJssOooGk", imageTag:"cat"},
{type: "gif", id: "BZ9K1QrgcJr20", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/dog-puppy-BZ9K1QrgcJr20", imageTag: "dog"},
{type: "gif", id: "E5EUmJssOooGk", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-E5EUmJssOooGk", imageTag:"cat"}
].sort((a,b)=>a.imageTag>b.imageTag?1:a.imageTag<b.imageTag?-1:0);

console.log(data);
```

Если вам нужно отфильтровать массив объектов по тегу, используйте `.filter()`:

```js
let data = [{type: "gif", id: "BZ9K1QrgcJr20", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/dog-puppy-BZ9K1QrgcJr20", imageTag: "dog",},
{type: "gif", id: "E5EUmJssOooGk", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-E5EUmJssOooGk", imageTag:"cat"},
{type: "gif", id: "BZ9K1QrgcJr20", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/dog-puppy-BZ9K1QrgcJr20", imageTag: "dog"},
{type: "gif", id: "E5EUmJssOooGk", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-E5EUmJssOooGk", imageTag:"cat"}
].filter(a=>a.imageTag=='cat');

console.log(data);
```

Можно использовать и `.reduce()`, если вы понимаете как он работает:

```js
let data = [{type: "gif", id: "BZ9K1QrgcJr20", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/dog-puppy-BZ9K1QrgcJr20", imageTag: "dog",},
{type: "gif", id: "E5EUmJssOooGk", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-E5EUmJssOooGk", imageTag:"cat"},
{type: "gif", id: "BZ9K1QrgcJr20", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/dog-puppy-BZ9K1QrgcJr20", imageTag: "dog"},
{type: "gif", id: "E5EUmJssOooGk", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-E5EUmJssOooGk", imageTag:"cat"}
]

console.log(data.reduce((r,v)=>((r[v.imageTag]||(r[v.imageTag]=[])).push(v),r),{}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let oldArr = {
      0: {type: "gif", id: "BZ9K1QrgcJr20", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/dog-puppy-BZ9K1QrgcJr20", imageTag: "dog"},
      1: {type: "gif", id: "E5EUmJssOooGk", url: "https://giphy.com/gifs/cat-E5EUmJssOooGk", imageTag: "cat"}
    }, newArr = {};
    
for(let i = 0; i < Object.keys(oldArr).length; i++) {
  if(!newArr[oldArr[i]['imageTag']]) newArr[oldArr[i]['imageTag']] = [];
  newArr[oldArr[i]['imageTag']].push(oldArr[i]);
}

console.info(newArr);
```